# Delegate method is not being called and giving a nil value

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

For some reason, the delegate method is not being called. I am printing the delegate property in the console but it returns nil. I was looking for other answers here, but none of them were helpful for me.

```
protocol FilterSwitchDelegate {
    func switchValueChanged(tagValue:Int)
}

class FilterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var filterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var filterSwitch: UISwitch!

    var delegate:FilterSwitchDelegate?

    @IBAction func filterSwitchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        print(sender.tag)

        delegate?.switchValueChanged(tagValue: sender.tag)      
    }
}
```

//In FilterViewController I am calling this delegate method

```
class FilterViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var dataSource = FilterTableViewCell()
    var filterModel = [FilterVCDataModel]()
    var ids = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataSource.delegate = self
    }
}

extension FilterViewController: FilterSwitchDelegate {
    func switchValueChanged(tagValue: Int) {
        ids.remove(at: tagValue)
        print(ids)
    }
}
```

TableView dataSource and delegate methods

```
extension FilterViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filterModel.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filterCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterTableViewCell
        cell.filterSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.filterLabel.text = filterModel[indexPath.row].filterData["title"] as? String
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 66
    }        
}
```

Comment: Show the tableview datasource methods

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of `FilterTableViewCell` this way? Show how you use this `dataSource` property.

Comment: You need to assign the delegate when the cell is dequeued -(i.e. in the  `cellForRowAt` function)

Comment: Get rid of that needless `dataSource` property in `FilterViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `cellForRow` you have to dequeue your cell.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourId") as? FilterTableViewCell

cell.delegate = self

return cell
```

and the job is done